# VBA ontime cancel scheduling

Tags: excel, ontime, vba

I have written a macro that runs at 15:30pm every workday when a workbook is first opened.
When the workbook is closed it tries to open itself the next time the macro is scheduled to run. I have tried to turn the scheduler to false and am getting an error. Code below.
Has anyone any ideas why this isn't working?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:30:00"), "MacroTimeTest"
End Sub

public dtime as date

Sub MacroTimeTest()

    dtime = (Format(Application.Evaluate("workday(today(), 1)"), "DD/MM/YY") & " " & TimeValue("15:30:00"))

    'other code has been deleted doesn't affect dtime variable 
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    'I have tried replacing false with 0 etc but it didn't make a difference
    Application.OnTime earliesttime:=dtime, procedure:="MacroTimeTest", schedule:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to let people know what the error was!

Comment: I'm guessing it would be `Method OnTime of object _application' failed`. But the OP should edit their question to confirm.

Comment: Yes, I apologise for not putting enough detail, thanks for the tips. Will be useful when I have to ask more questions, also thanks to Raj for formatting the code

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should keep a reference to the time so that you can cancel the action. You can only cancel an action if it hasn't already executed.

In `ThisWorkbook` enter the following to run the macro at 15:59 until the sheet is closed

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error GoTo CouldNotCancel

    Application.OnTime dTime, "MacroTimeTest", , False
    Debug.Print "Cancelled task to run at " & dTime

    Debug.Print "Workbook close"

    Exit Sub


CouldNotCancel:
    Debug.Print "No task to cancel"

End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Debug.Print "Workbook open"

    dTime = TimeValue("15:59:00")

    Debug.Print "Next run time " & dTime
    Application.OnTime dTime, "MacroTimeTest"

End Sub
```

Then add your macro to a Module

```
Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date
Public Sub MacroTimeTest()

    'schedule next run
    dTime = TimeValue("15:59:00")

    'schedule next run
    Debug.Print "Scheduling next run at " & dTime

    Application.OnTime dTime, "MacroTimeTest"

    Debug.Print "Running macro"

End Sub
```

This way the same value of `dTime` will be used to cancel the scheduled task as was used to create it.

If no further task has been scheduled i.e. by an error in MacroTimeTest then the Workbook close event will handle the error.

To see the debug output look at the immediate window in the VBA Editor (Ctrl+G)